# Odd Even String- Python

Tags: python

Write a function named `evenOddString()` that takes a single string parameter.

If the length of the string parameter:

- is odd: `evenOddString()` should return the string parameter.
- is even, `evenOddString()` should return the string parameter concatenated with itself.

This is my code so far:

```
def evenOddString():
    len(var) % 2 != 0
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Tagging as homework, as that's rather obvious. What part of this question are you having trouble with?

Comment: It seems like they don't know about function parameters, the return keyword, and if statements.

Comment: Seems like the pseudo-code aspect of it is on the right track though.

Comment: Maybe try passing a "single string parameter"

Comment: You have three very helpful answers, one of which is the solution. Try implementing something and vote on or accept answers.

Answer (score 3):

First, your evenOddString() function needs to take a parameter.  For example:

```
def evenOddString(the_string_parameter):
  print(the_string_parameter)
```

To call that function, you would have something like:

```
evenOddString('abc123')
```

which would print out abc123 on the console.  In your case, you will want check the length of the_string_parameter and do some stuff with it "if" the length is even or odd.  The if and elif statements will be helpful. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html for docs on flow control.

You also want to return a value back out of your function.  If I wanted to return the string unchanged, I would do something like:

```
def evenOddString(the_string_parameter):
  return the_string_parameter
```

Note that I'm being a little vague here as this sounds like a homework assignment and I don't want to simply write all the code for you.  Since you sound like a new programmer just starting out and in need of a good tutorial, I highly recommend you work through http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Answer (score 2):

1. define a function that take a parameter - Your definition does not take a parameter
2. get the length of that parameter - No problems here
3. if the length is odd, return the return the parameter - Your condition is correct, but you're not doing anything with the condition
4. else: return the parameter concatenated with itself - not implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
def control4OddString(myString):
    if len(myString) % 2: return myString
    else: return myString+myString
```